# Working with XML file with tags with different ids attributes

Tags: r, xml

This is my xml file:

```
<Games>
    <Game id = 1>
    <Q>1</Q>
    <Q>Rick</Q>
    <Q>623.3</Q>
    <Q>1/1/2012</Q>
    <Q>IT</Q>
    </Game>
    
    <Game id = 2>
    <Q>2</Q>
    <Q>Dan</Q>
    <Q>515.2</Q>
    <Q>9/23/2013</Q>
    <Q>Operations</Q>
    </Game>
    
    <Game id = 3>
    <Q>3</Q>
    <Q>Michelle</Q>
    <Q>611</Q>
    <Q>11/15/2014</Q>
    <Q>IT</Q>
    </Game>
    
    <Game id = 4>
    <Q>4</Q>
    <Q>Ryan</Q>
    <Q>729</Q>
    <Q>5/11/2014</Q>
    <Q>HR</Q>
    </Game>
    
    <Game id = 5>
    <Q>5</Q>
    <Q>Gary</Q>
    <Q>843.25</Q>
    <Q>3/27/2015</Q>
    <Q>Finance</Q>
    </Game>
    
    <Game id = 6>
    <Q>6</Q>
    <Q>Nina</Q>
    <Q>578</Q>
    <Q>5/21/2013</Q>
    <Q>IT</Q>
    </Game>
    
    
    
</Games>
```

The tags `Game`have ids and other attributes. Using `game <- xml_find_all(xml_file, xpath = "//Games/Game")` and then `game_attr_dataframe <- xml_attrs(game_node) %>% as.data.frame()`

I am able to extract all the `Game` Tags and organize them in a dataframe.

The problem is when I do the same to extract the children `Game` tag `Q`.

I do this: `q <- xml_find_all(xml_file, xpath = "//Games/Game/Q")` and then `q_attr <- xml_attrs(q_node)`

The result is a huge `"xml_nodeset"` vector and I lost which `Q` tag belongs to which `Game` with its respectively `id`.

If somehow I can identify from what id attribute Game tag the q_attr elemnts came from my proble would be solved.

Am I clear? Please let me kno.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

with library `XML` this should work (but be prepared for errors when attribute values are not enclosed with `"`)

```
library(XML)
library(methods)

xmlToDataFrame('your-xml-file.xml')
## Q   NA    NA        NA         NA
## 1 1 Rick 623.3  1/1/2012         IT
## 2 2  Dan 515.2 9/23/2013 Operations
## ...

## <Game id = 1> throws an error
## <Game id = "1"> works
```